# Email attachments recorded in Excel

Tags: email, excel, outlook, email-attachments, vba

The macro below is designed to take x amount of emails, count how many attachments there are in each mail and then locate certain file formats. It will then record what it has found in a certain excel spreadsheet.

The macro works perfectly, but I am now wanting to add in another scenario. The scenario I want to add in is that of if an email has more than 1 .csv file, it shall be recorded as "Multiple" rather than "YES".

Has anyone got any ideas to implement this scenario?

```
        If .Attachments.Count = 0 Then
        csv_report = "NO"
        pdf_report = "NO"
        xls_report = "NO"
        End If

        If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        For i2 = 1 To .Attachments.Count
        If LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".csv" Then
        csv_report = "YES"
        GoTo CSVyes        'if a .csv file is found, it skips to the PDF attachment checker
        Else
        csv_report = "NO"
        End If
        Next

CSVyes:
        For i2 = 1 To .Attachments.Count
        If LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
        pdf_report = "YES"
        GoTo PDFyes        'if a .pdf file is found, it skips to the XLS attachment checker
        Else
        pdf_report = "NO"
        End If
        Next

PDFyes:
        For i2 = 1 To .Attachments.Count
        If LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".xls" Or LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 5)) = ".xlsx" Or UCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".XLS" Then
        xls_report = "YES"
        GoTo XLSyes        'if a .xls file is found, it skips to the end of the checks
        Else
        xls_report = "NO"
        End If
        Next

XLSyes:
        End If

        Sheets("Mail Report").Activate
        Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = csv_report
        Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = pdf_report
        Range("E65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = xls_report

        subject_line = mail.Subject
        Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = subject_line
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear. But that will cause an email with 1 .csv file to show up as "Multiple". I want it to stay as "YES" for 1, but be "Multiple" for when theres more than 1

Comment: Chek my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts to implement this scenario, I was unsuccessful. So I figured to put an alternative method after this macro.

This macro is just a minor part of a much larger scale macro, but basically when there was blanks left in Column B I would replace a "YES" with "Multiple", which was sufficient to the outcome.

```
Dim kk As Long

Sheets("Mail Report").Activate
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For kk = 1 To LastRow
If IsEmpty(Cells(kk, 2)) Then
    Cells(kk, 2) = MAIN_PATH & "For Resolution\" & "multiple_csv\"
    Cells(kk, 3) = "MULTIPLE"
End If
Next kk
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this below code. I have just added `If Else` block to check if Attachment.count > 1. THat's It.

```
If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    For i2 = 1 To .Attachments.Count
    If LCase(Right(.Attachments(i2).Filename, 4)) = ".csv" Then
    If .Attachments.Count > 1
       csv_report = "MULTIPLE"
    Else
       csv_report = "YES"
    End If
    GoTo CSVyes        'if a .csv file is found, it skips to the PDF attachment checker
    Else
    csv_report = "NO"
    End If
    Next
```

Comment: That will not work. This is the process: Email is selected - if attachments count is greater then - first attachment selected - if .csv file - "YES" (Go to PDF) - if not .csv file - "NO" (Go to PDF) - repeat process for PDF and XLS check with same attachment.

Comment: I am confused by this line - "if .csv file - "YES" (Go to PDF) - if not .csv file - "NO" (Go to PDF)". Please clarify